# Erro ao limpar um DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

Depois que eu salvei meus itens que estão no DataGrid em uma base de dados, gostaria que limpasse. Portanto utilizei da seguinte maneira:

```
dg.Items.Clear();
```

Mas dai aparece esse erro:

> Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Ele esta sendo usado ou algo parecido? Como solucionar isso?

Comment: Posta o resto do código, como você está fazendo pra atribuir o `ItemsSource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já experimentou fazer isso aqui:

```
dg.ItemsSource = null;
dg.Items.Refresh();
```

Comment: Dessa maneira funcionou sim. Mas fiquei pensando, isso é boa prática né? e não vou ter problema na hora de add ou fazer alguma alteração?

Comment: Não sei se é a melhor prática, mas dessa forma você limpa a referência ao `source` anterior e fica livre pro resto.

Comment: Muito obrigado :D